# Showing current GIT branch permanently in terminal

Tags: git, macos, bash, terminal

How do I permanently show the current GIT branch in my terminal. After I follow the steps mentioned in [here](http://code-worrier.com/blog/git-branch-in-bash-prompt/), I get the results but once I quit and re-launch terminal, changes are gone. Also, I do not see colour combinations as mentioned in here.

Please advise.

PS: I am using MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not looked at zsh and/or prezto yet, take a look here:
http://codurance.com/2015/03/16/installing-zprezto-a-quick-guide/

There are several themes that come with prezto which have what you are looking for and zsh has several neat features as well.

Comment: Awesome! This worked like a charm. How can I explore other features of **prezto**. Referred to ReadMe file as mentioned on github but it does not have much of information.

Comment: You can find more information in the Readme files for the modules: https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto/tree/master/modules

Answer (score 0):

The page says that you have to:

```
# Load in the git branch prompt script.
source ~/.git-prompt.sh
```

You do this once, but when you log out that step is lost.

To make it permanent, add that line into either your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` file that gets loaded when you log in.

In fact, it is stated in the page:

> Now modify your your bash profile (it’s at `~/.bash-profile` [sic, it has to be bash_profile], in case
>   you’re new to this stuff).

Comment: Well, this works only on current instance of terminal. If I quit and re-launch, I again have to execute - `source ~/.git-prompt.sh`.

Comment: @Abhinav this shouldn't be the case. Are you editing your `~/.bash_profile`?

Comment: Try closing all your terminal sessions and opening them again

Comment: @Bustikiller Tried but no luck. Looks like I will have to always execute `source ~/.git-prompt.sh` after a new terminal is launched.

Comment: @Abhinav this is quite unexpected. I would add some stuff in your `.bash_profile` to make sure it is even read on log in. For example, `touch /tmp/$(date)`, which will create a file in `/tmp` named after the date.

Comment: @Abhinav By default OSX run as a login shell for each opened terminal window, and therefore `.bash_profile` is sourced, But it is possible to change that. You might have changed it, and in that case you need to put the code in your `.bashrc` file instead.

Answer (score 0):

In order to show current git branch on ubuntu terminal :

1. Open the ~/.bashrc file with your favourite editor.
   (I did with nano : sudo nano ~/.bashrc)
2. Then add the following script:

```
     git_branch() {
          git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
        }
     export PS1="[\u@\h \W]\[\033[00;32m\]\$(git_branch)\[\033[00m\]\$ "
```

3. Load the bashrc file to reflect the branch using `source ~/.bashrc`